# PL/PQSQL Stored Procedure: What is the difference between this 2 type of approaches?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am new to Postgresql stored procedures. What is the differences between this 2 method? I know if I `Select * from function_name()`, I would still get a table.

Code 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_film (p_pattern VARCHAR) 
 RETURNS TABLE (
 film_title VARCHAR,
 film_release_year INT
)
```

Code 2

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.list_of_customers(
    OUT first_name character varying,
    OUT last_name character varying)
    RETURNS SETOF record 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are absolutely identical.

The `TABLE` syntax is more recent and more readable in my opinion, but you can choose whatever you prefer.

Comment: I tried using PgAdmin to return type pg_tables (I can't find output 'tables') but ran into some issue, but I can find 'record' and my test code work and that's prompted me to ask. Thank you very much.